# Is there any way to invoke a function which is nested inside another function?

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following function:

```js
function a() {

  function b() { 
    console.log('b') 
  }

  console.log('a')
  b()
}

a()
```

From the outer scope, when I invoke `function a()`, I get the following result

```
a()
> 'a'
> 'b'
```

Is there any way for me to invoke `function b()` directly from the outer scope without modifying the original function? From the outer scope I only have access to `a`. Something like this:

```
a.b()
> 'b'
```

I need any dirty solution possible.

Comment: No, you cannot. Is this [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Not possible without updating the function. One of the **reasons** people write functions that way is to prevent it from being called from outside.

Comment: @VLAZ The context is that I'm using npm `history` package which keeps track of the browser history in memory, but does not expose the history to the dev. I need access to the history and I prefer not to re-write my own implementation, but leverage on the original `history package`. Though I suppose the answer is that I should just be cloning their code instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing holding any reference to `b` after `a()` has run so it's completely inaccessible. Depending on what the end goal is - as a very dirty solution you *could* do `a.toString()` then dump the inner parts into an `eval`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it if you return a reference to that function from `a`, but you would have to modify it.

```
function a() {

  function b() { 
    console.log('b') 
  }

  console.log('a')
  b()

  return b;
}


const b = a()
b();
```

Comment: "*without modifying the original function*"